# How to copy an object by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have following case. That's what I'm trying to do:

```
std::vector < Shape > shapesArr;
Shape *shape = new Shape();
shape->someParam = someValue;
shapesArr.push_back( Shape );

// ...

Shape *shape2 = new Shape();
shape2 = shapesArr[ 0 ]; // <-- here I need a copy of that object to shapeA

delete[] shapesArr;
delete shape2; // <-- error, because it has already freed. It would be nice if I had a copy of shapesArr[ 0 ] in my shape2
```

How to properly copy that object to shape2? I need two copies of that object which will be stored in shapesArr[ 0 ] and shape2 separately.

Comment: You did not allocate `shapesArr` with `new`, why would you want to call `delete` on it?!

Comment: Your `vector` stores `Shape`, you make a heap allocated `Shape`, then ignore it and `push_back` the class, not the instance at all (even if you `push_back`-ed `shape` it would be wrong, because the `vector` stores `Shape`, not `Shape*`). You also try to `delete[]` your `shapesArr` `vector` which isn't even on the heap. This code would never compile. Please make a [MCVE]; this is useless as is. I suspect the real answer here is "don't use the heap at all and everything just works".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Shape *shape2 = new Shape(shapesArr[0]);` to create a copy.

There are two errors in your code:

First:

```
std::vector < Shape > shapesArr;
Shape *shape = new Shape();
shape->someParam = someValue;
// you should push *shape, because Shape is just the class name
// and shape is a Shape* type pointer
// you can shapesArr.push_back( *shape );
shapesArr.push_back( Shape );
```

Second, you can't delete the vector, because you didn't new a vector, if you want to erase all the element in the vector, use `shapesArr.clear()` or `shapesArr.erase(shapesArr.begin(),shapesArr.end());`